# Solution of differential equation- Change of variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have the differential equation $y''+ \frac{p}{x} y'+ \frac{q}{x^2}y=0, x>0$ and we set $z=\log x$.

Then we have the differential equation:

$$\frac{d^2y}{dz^2}+(p-1) \frac{dy}{dz}+qy=0 (*)$$

We are looking for a solution of the form $e^{rz}$.

$e^{rz}$ is a solution iff

$$r^2+(p-1)r+q=0$$

If $r_1, r_2$ two distinct real roots then $y_1(z)=e^{r_1 z}, y_2(z)=e^{r_2 z}$ are linearly indepent solutions of $(*)$ and so $y_1(x)=x^{r_1}, y_2(x)=x^{r_2}$ are linearly independent solutions of $y''+\frac{p}{x}y'+\frac{q}{x^2}y=0, x>0$.

How do we get that  $y_1(x)=x^{r_1}, y_2(x)=x^{r_2}$?

I thought that it would be as follows: 
$y_1(z)=e^{r_1 z} \Rightarrow y_1(\log x)=e^{r_1 \log x} \Rightarrow y_1(\log{e^x})=e^{r_1 \log{e^x}} \Rightarrow y_1(x)=e^{r_1 x}$. 
Where am I wrong?

**EDIT:**

It holds that $y_1(z)=e^{r_1 z}=(e^{z})^{r_1}=(e^{\log x})^{r_1}=x^{r_1}$.

So $y_1(\log x)= x^{r_1}$.

How do we get that $y_1(x)=x^{r_1}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are confused because you are using the same name $y_1$ for both functions: $$f(z) = e^{r_1z}, g(x) = x^{r_1}$$  what you have is $$f(z(x)) = g(x) \text{ where } z = \ln x. $$

Comment: A ok.. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

You're actually doing:
$$\frac{dy}{dz}\equiv\frac{dy(x)}{dz(x)}=\frac{dy(x)/dx}{dz(x)/dx}=\frac{dy(x)}{dx}.\frac1{1/x}=x\frac{dy}{dx}$$
which you're treating as $y(\log x)$. remember $z$ or $x$ when written as $y(z),y(x)$ are only dummy variables.

Comment: Then we have the following:

$$r_1 e^{r_1 x}=x \frac{dy}{dx} \Rightarrow dy=\frac{1}{x} r_1 e^{r_1 z} dx \Rightarrow y=\ln x r_1 e^{r_1 z}+c \Rightarrow y=\ln x r_1 e^{r_1 \log x}+c=\ln x r_1 x^{r_1}+c$$

Or am I wrong? But how do we get to the desired result?

Comment: @evinda $e^{r_1\log x}=x^{r_1}$

Comment: I edited my question. Could you take a look at it?